# “No system images installed for this target” Xamarin AVD Manager

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk, xamarin.android

Anytime I select a target for Google APIs it tells me there are no system images available. I have completely removed and reinstalled every available option in SDK manager. For the API Level I am trying to use, I have every available image installed. Also I have tried copying the images out of the default folder as suggested by another question's answer and restarting visual studio.

[AVD Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdQmT.png)

[SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMKDC.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the issue by selecting a standard api lvel target (non google apis) and then for CPU select one that included google apis. Was following this tutorial on [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/) that told me to select the target with google apis, but apparently that does not work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Google's Android SDK Installer (that Xamarin runs during the base install), does not install system images for each API due to their size (1+GB each).

Open the Android SDK Manager and select/install which versions you want, they are available by API-level.

**Note:** For HAXM acceleration to function you need the x86 / x86_64 based images, ARM versions will run, BUT very slowly...

**Note:** The Images whose names start with `"Google APIs ...."` have Google Apps pre-installed.

[image]

Comment: If you look at the SDK Manager image I attached, you would see ALL of the available system images are installed for the API Level I am working with.

Comment: @DreamC0der I did not look at images.... I would recommend you try this. Install Android Studio (you can share the already installed Android SDK so it will not download again) and open Android AVM via `Tools/Android/AVD Manager`. You will see the "new" Android Studio AVD Manager and see if it works to create a virtual device (they will be seen by Xamarin also). There are some Google Android group threads concerning/issues that the "older" AVD Manager is being deprecated, but I have not seen this officially stated but seems that fixes a lot of issues with AVD creation.