# How to solve AVD Google API "No system Image installed for this target"?

Tags: android, xamarin, google-api, android-virtual-device, azure-notificationhub

I have developed Xamarin app in VS, and I would like to use azure notification HUb to push notification to the app, 
based on [Get started with Notification Hubs with Xamarin for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm). If we run app in the emulator, we need to make sure that you use an Android Virtual Device (AVD) that supports Google APIs.

I am trying to use AVD, I checked  Android virtual Device, (Tool , Android,Android Emulator Manger) the target is not Google APIs, and if I try to changed the CPU textbox become disabled with the message "No system Image installed for this target"
[image]

I have installed all required packaged in Android SDK Manger for emulator API level

[image]

Anyone has any ideas how to fix the grayed out box/message?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308175/no-system-images-installed-for-this-target-xamarin-avd-manager), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886706/no-system-images-installed-for-this-target-even-though-image-is-installed) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541681/fail-to-create-android-virtual-device-no-system-image-installed-for-this-targe)?

Comment: I have tried all of them it doesn't work , and the scanrio 
"selecting a standard api level target (non google apis) and then for CPU select one that included google apis". is not what i am looking for , I am able to carete AVD but dosn't work to get noitification

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In the original question you asked about the error message when selecting a target. Now you're saying that you can deploy, but you don't get messages. If there're two separate problems, please create a separate question describing what exactly is wrong with notifications. Because now it seems like the question has nothing to do with Azure services, but about your local dev environment.

Comment: I have mentioned at the begining of the  question "I have developed Xamarin app in VS, and I would like to use azure notification HUb to push notification to the app, based on Get started with Notification Hubs with Xamarin for Android. If we run app in the emulator, we need to make sure that you use an Android Virtual Device (AVD) that supports Google APIs." So i think it was clear enough i need the AVD with target of google API

Comment: Is it possible that you have two installs of the Android SDK? Since it seems you do have the correct system image loaded in the screen shot, this is the only thing I can think of. Make sure the path shown at the top of the Android SDK Manager is the same as set in Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android